# Create different log names at each execution time in Python

Tags: python

```
    import os
    import logging
    os.chdir("C:\Users\SIT\Desktop\Powersupply")
    logging.basicConfig(
        filename='mylog{0}.txt'.format(i),
        format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',
        datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'
        )
    logging.warning(123)
```

As above , When I execute it once , I want the file name to generate different log names .

```
ex:
Once -> mylog(0)
Second->mylog(1)
third ->mylog(3)
```

Comment: Check the directory for file names matching mylog*.txt, find the latest one, then create a new one with the next number.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
time_string = now.strftime( '%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S' )
file_name = 'mylog_%s.txt' % time_string
```